# Rails (ERB): Can I cancel a fragment cache if a condition fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, erb

I'm looking for a simple and efficient way to cancel a cache write for a named fragment in an ERB view if a condition fails.

I am currently doing this:

```
<% cache("header_#{$I18n.locale}", expires_in: 1.day) do %>
  <% begin %>
      <%= raw open("https://mywebsite.org/remote/fragment", :read_timeout => 10).read %>
  <% rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e %>
    Error Loading Remote File: <%= e.message %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously some of this is just to demonstrate my problem, not to show a best practice for production code.

**Here's the problem:** The above will cache the error message and show it for 1 day instead of retrying the server on the next load.

(Usually this would not be happening in a view, but in this case I'm writing a plugin for a bigger rails app and can't modify the controller, just the view.)

**This is what I'd like to do:**

```
<% cache("header_#{$I18n.locale}", expires_in: 1.day) do %>
  <% begin %>
      <%= raw open("https://mywebsite.org/remote/fragment", :read_timeout => 10).read %>
  <% rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e %>
    --> Some command to cancel the cache action started above
    --> Show a backup something to the user (I'll provide)
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how this can be done?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer to this, but my two suggestions would be to a) put the `cache` call _inside_ the `begin` block, so the exception being raised exits the call to `cache` before it completes, and possibly b) if necessary, also use the [`expire_fragment` method](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment)

Comment: @philomory Your suggestion of putting the cache call inside the begin block is working correctly in my testing. Can you make this an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to cache the result when there's an exception, you should put your exception-handling code outside the `cache` block:

```
<% begin %>
  <% cache("header_#{$I18n.locale}", expires_in: 1.day) do %>
    <%= raw open("https://mywebsite.org/remote/fragment", :read_timeout => 10).read %>
  <% end %>
<% rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e %>
  Error Loading Remote File: <%= e.message %>
<% end %>
```

That way, when an exception is raised inside the cache block, that block will be exited before it completes and no caching will occur.

Answer (score -1):

> There are two hard problems in computer science: naming things, cache invalidation, and off-by-one errors.

Welcome to the second hard problem.

Try using `Rails.cache` instead of `cache` - I'm not 100% on what the difference is or if there even is one, but `Rails.cache` gets you some more obvious methods for cache operations.

`Rails.cache.fetch` takes three options: the cache key, an options hash, and a block. If the specified key exists in the cache and is not expired, it'll return the contents of the cache; otherwise, it'll execute the block and store its results in the cache.

```
<% Rails.cache.fetch "header_#{$I18n.locale}", :expires_in => 1.day do %>
  <% begin %>
    <%= raw open("https://mywebsite.org/remote/fragment", :read_timeout => 10).read %>
  <% rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e %>
    <% Rails.cache.delete "header_#{$I18n.locale}" # removes the cache entry %>
    <!-- Show your backup here -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If that doesn't work, it's likely down to the order the cache operations are done in - it may be that the entry gets deleted in your `rescue` block, but then re-added when the entire block has finished executing. In that case, try this:

```
<% remove_cache_entry = false %>

<% Rails.cache.fetch "header_#{$I18n.locale}", :expires_in => 1.day do %>
  <% begin %>
    <%= raw open("https://mywebsite.org/remote/fragment", :read_timeout => 10).read %>
  <% rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e %>
    <% remove_cache_entry = true %>
    <!-- Show your backup here -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% Rails.cache.delete "header_#{$I18n.locale}" if remove_cache_entry %>
```

Comment: I tested the first method and I can confirm that this does not work. I monitored the cache keys at each step through the process and the key is not written before the end of the cache block, therefore doing Rails.cache.delete doesn't yet have a key to delete. I did not test the second block, but based on what I know it should work and in some cases might be best. It is not the simplest solution when dealing with exceptions, that goes to @philomory in his comment. Since the write is not executed until the very end of the block, a raised exception will prevent the write from ever happening.